# Удаление из БД SQLite записей старше 7 дней

Tags: sql, sqlite

Не удаляются почему-то устаревшие записи. Что неправильно у меня, подскажите, пожалуйста:

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM `property` WHERE strftime('%s',created_at)<(strftime('%s','now')-(3600*24*7))");
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке новых данных в БД одновременно удалялись записи старше 7 дней из таблицы property .

Спасибо

Я использую SQLite, там есть strftime.
created_at - тип поля DATETIME

Comment: А вы уверены что в mysql (или какая там БД у вас) есть `strftime`?

Comment: и created_at - тип поля какой?

Comment: Mike, так? $db->query("DELETE FROM `property` WHERE created_at < now() - interval 7 day");   Я ж чайник, слабо ориентируюсь в предмете

Comment: Ну в sqlite явно по другому. надо в метках к вопросу всегда сразу указывать СУБД. Судя по всему `created_at < datetime('now','-7 day')`. Проверьте это для начала на select, убедитесь что он дал именно те записи, которые надо удалять

Comment: Ура! Все работает!  СПАСИБО, Mike! Оформите ответом, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий, чтобы я могла его выбрать лучшим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заданное время относительно указанной даты в SQLite возвращает функция [datetime()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Записи старше 7 дней находятся и удаляются так:

```
DELETE FROM property WHERE created_at < datetime('now','-7 day')
```